# Expressjs rerouting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

I need to make routing flexible for slashes, for example

```
app.get('/home/pages')
```

router must handle

```
////home///pages 
/home/pages//// 
etc...
```

requests.

Currently I have one idea to implement this, but for that I need to know how to reroute request via middleware,

If you can answer this question or suggest something else I will be grateful to you.

Also please **don't suggest** using **regex** for defining routers, because project is already done and there is a lot of already defined routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rewrite url in a middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/\/+/g, '/');
    next();
});


app.get('/home/pages', function (req, res) {
    res.send('some pages');
});

app.listen(3000);
```